# Language limit resource .resx

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a resource file that has 350 lines, I calculate approximately and I'll get to about 500 lines.

Does this influences the performance of the application?

Is there a limit of lines for resource file?

I use this for text messages or controls or tooltips

Comment: RESX content is compiled and loaded into memory, so unless you go crazy on it with like 100K or more entries, CPU won't even blink at it. There might be a physical limit like for Excel files (65k), but not that i heard of. However for the sake of maintenance, you might wanna split it into smaller categorized files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

500 lines of data is nothing! That can be read/stored quickly, really 500 lines is nothing.

You could store the resource content into an String Array to gain better performance instead of reading each line of the resource again and again (if you are doing that).

An Executable greater than 4 GB can't be executed, so the limit is there (And in the amount of RAM avaliable on the PC), I don't know if Compiler prevents compilations greater than 4 gb, but never you will need to store a textfile of that sizes.

I've tried now just for curiosity to add a resource textfile which contains 10.000.000 of lines, the file size is 234 mb, and the UI of the compiled exe works perfectly, the process RAM consumption in the TaskManager displays only 7 mb (before loading the resource), after loading the resource it sums a total of 940 MB, I don't know exactly why (remember that the textfile filesize is only 234 mb).

I hope this helped you something.